# How to replace "^@" with "\r"

Tags: regex, vim, regex-greedy

I have a script contains certain functions/replaces,etc..

But in my output, contains some junks like `^@`.

How to replace this `^@` with a newline? with the script

This command executes in vim commandline `%s/<CTRL-2>//g`, but not by script

Comment: if your script mean vim script, then you can use it like your vim command line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^@` is ASCII 0.

You could use:

```
sed 's/\x00/\n/g'
```

Comment: E492: Not an editor command:               sed 's/\x00/\n/g'

Comment: You asked for a script. It is not a vi command!

Comment: oh! is there any way to include this to my vimscript

Comment: no idea. It is not the same question.

Answer (score 2):

#### type command in vim

If you want to fix the result, you could do this in vim:

```
:%s/
```

then press:

```
<Ctrl-V>010
```

After that your command looks like: `:%s/^@`

Then you can continue typing:

```
:%s/^@/\r/g
```

But I think the better solution is fixing the codes which generated these chars.

#### in script

If you want to do it in script, there is function : `nr2char()` you could do `nr2char(10)` to get the `^@`

Comment: probably `append` or another call to a system thing. I added a link to a similar problem which I had once, in the question comments.

Comment: @sidyll I don't know where did the `^@` come from, OP didn't say that. It could be from external command (system()) or append() or just a wrong sub: e.g. `:s/foo/\n/`. so I don't see the need of `append/system` trick so far.

Comment: is is possible "%s/nr2char(10)/\r/g"?

Comment: @SamjithDasan no. but you can do `:exec ...` and concatenate the command

Comment: i have not much experience in vim, could you give me an example

Comment: @SamjithDasan `:h :exe`, there are many examples telling you how to concatenate commands

Comment: no idea!. execute "nr2char(10)" "\r" and failed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98115/discussion-between-samjith-dasan-and-kent).

Comment: @SamjithDasan `nr2char()` gives you the `^@`,  You are the boss of how to do with it. You can call `substitute()` function, you can cancatenate `:s/../../` command...  If you wrote `:exec "nr2char(10)"`   you didn't read or understand the help doc. Anyway, the question was marked as duplicates, just check the duplicated question and answers and find help.