# Substituting ^M in nvim script

Tags: regex, macos, vim, zsh, neovim

Environment:

> OS X: 10.11.3
>
> NeoVim: 0.1.2-dev
>
> set fileformat=unix

The following vim function runs a zsh script which returns the page title, URL, last modified time and current date and time.

```
function! SafariURL()
let saf_data=system(shellescape('/Users/xxx/Documents/zsh scripts/saf_grab.sh'))
let saf_sub=substitute(saf_data, "^M", "\r","g")
call append(17,saf_sub)
end function
```

The saf_grab.sh script contains the following code:

```
mytext=$(/usr/bin/osascript << END
tell application "Safari"
set selecTxt to (do JavaScript "(getSelection().toString())" in document 1)
set pgTitl to (do JavaScript "document.title" in document 1)
set pgDate to (do JavaScript "document.lastModified" in document 1)
set myURL to URL of front document
set copyText to selecTxt  &  "[" & pgTitl & "]" & "(" & myURL & ")" & return & "Page Last Modified:" & pgDate & return & "Clipped On:" & (current date)
return copyText 
end
END)

echo $mytext
echo "$mytext" |  bcopy
```

For some reason the string which is returned by sf_grab.sh inserts `^M` as line breaks as shown below:

`[Newline - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia]^M(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)^MPage Last Modified:01/16/2016 13:07:02^MClipped On:Tuesday, 2 February 2016 at 11:00:37^@`

I have tried to make a substitution in the vim function to replace these characters by `\r` but it results in the `^M` being replaced with `^M`.

If I change the substitution to `\n` instead of `\r`, then the `^M`'s are replaced with `^@`.

I don't understand why the original script returns `^M`'s in the first place and how to replace them with line breaks as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your vim function in vim itself, and write ^M by

steps

1. Enable insert mode
2. Press Control + Shift + v
3. Press Control + Shift + m

> ```
> function! SafariURL()
> let saf_data=system(shellescape('/Users/xxx/Documents/zsh scripts/saf_grab.sh'))
> let saf_sub=substitute(saf_data, "^M", "\r","g")
> call append(17,saf_sub)
> %s/^M/\r/g
> end function
> ```

Comment: Replacing with `\r` inserts `^M`. See my comment to @Dasan

Comment: Try %s/^M/\r/g after append

Comment: That worked. Thank you. 
Do you have any idea why `let saf_sub=substitute(saf_data, "^M", "\r","g")` does not work?

Comment: These are ASCII characters.  if we did some search (\n) and replace (\r) with in a variable like "saf_sub", it will produce ^M instead of  this newline. But if we replace directly with in the vim itself, it works.

Comment: Anyway, if the answer is really helpful, please accept the answer and up vote me. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below link, it may help

[[How to replace "^@" with "\r"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290247/how-to-replace-with-r?noredirect=1#comment56323919_34290247][1])

OR
a simple solution ( i know it is not the proper way)

First replace \n with some text which will not been come ever, like "@@newline@@" in your saf_grab.sh

and revert "@@newline@@" with "\r".

```
let saf_sub=substitute(saf_data, "@@newline@@", "\r","g")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I had already tried something similar.  Replacing `"@@newline@@"` with `/r`, still produces `^M` in the output. If I replace with `/n`, then I get `^@` in the output instead of a new line. I believe it is how nVim is interpreting a new line character but I don't understand why it should be a problem as I have the `fileformat=unix`.

Comment: use \r instead of  /r

Comment: I am using `\r` just typed it incorrectly in the comment